# Enabling the keyboard lamp on X220?

Tags: lenovo

Fn-PgUp key is supposed to turn on the little keyboard lamp on Lenovo. It used to work on my T61 and older models, but no longer on X220. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Please run `sudo acpi_listen` in the terminal, press `Fn+PgUp` and edit answer/comment with what code appears.

Comment: Nothing. The above command does not yield any output in response to Fn+PgUp. It does generate codes for other Fn combinations, but not for this one.

Comment: Does it work when in BIOS?

Comment: It works when I boot it up in Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Figuring out the key code emitted by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

- You can use the [lsinput](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/lsinput.8.htmland) and [input-events](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/input-events.8.html) commands to look at the output of the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> combination.
- Then you can assign the key combination via the ACPI Event Definition as defined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys).

#### 2. Shell commands to switch on-off: can be integrated in ACPI Events, shortcut keys, etc.

Switch on the lamp:

`echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness`

Switch off the lamp:

`echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness`

---

For more information regarding ThinkLight on Linux:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkLight

Comment: OP wants to use the key combo, not soft control.

Comment: @izx I have improved my answer.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the implementation details?

Comment: @YossiGil As izx mentioned, **does the lamp work while you are in BIOS menu screen?**
Furthermore what is the output of `lsmod |grep thinkpad` .

Why I'm keeping downvoted ??

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. The echo command does not work in that it does not change the light status. Further, I still cannot figure out the scan code.

Comment: @YossiGil: `lsmod | grep thinkpad` as pl1nk asked, please -- the `thinkpad_acpi` module may not even be loaded. That's the only reason the `echo` commands wouldn't work.

Comment: @izx: I'm having the same problem.. the echo command does not switch on the light, even though the `thinkpad_acpi` module is loaded. Any suggestions? I don't really know where to start looking for a solution.